# What is the Android program size limit?

Tags: android

I want to know what is the Android program size limit:

1. Memory size limit for one process?
2. Code size limit for one application?

Comment: Wouldn't this also depend on the device it's running on?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but if you go by the presentation of Dan Bornstein, only available memory for apps is 20MB

Answer (score 0):

1. [It seems the default is 16 MB](http://tordtech.blogspot.com/2009/09/memory-limit-on-android.html) but rooted devices can change that.
2. APK size is limited to 50 MB (per an e-mail I have from Google)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried to use a 26M jars in my project (just for testing purpose), and I failed when converting to APK.

Comment: Failed how? And you say 26 MB jar(S) which implies more than one which would put you over the 50 MB limit.

Comment: No. I only have a 26M jar library and a very small Activity class. The whole size should be under 50MB for sure.